# What is the proper term for synchronizing my production files with my committed development files using Git?

Tags: git, github

I create Crystal Reports for use with a software application. The application grabs these from a folder on a networked drive (production). I keep a separate copy of these reports on another networked drive (development), where I make changes and create new reports. I have recently create a Git repository on my development files, since this added version control.

When I make a change to my development files, I commit the change and push the changes to my GitHub remote repository. I'd also like to push the change to my production folder; but I only need the current version of the file in production.

I've looked at resources like *How to Deploy a Website to a Remote Server Using GIT* (https://hackernoon.com/deploy-website-to-remote-server-using-git-da6048805637) and Lemiorhan's Post receive hook (https://gist.github.com/lemiorhan/8912188); but these entail a local copy of the repository, and a separate copy of the master branch. I'd prefer to avoid proliferating copies of the files.

I'm a total NOOB to Git, and am comfortable with creating repositories, staging and snapshoting changes, creating and merging branches; but beyond that everything gets hazy. I'm not whether Git can accomplish what I want to accomplish, or what the terminology is for what I want to accomplish. Am I cloning? Fetching? Pulling? Deploying? I'm sure the solution has already been given on SO, but without knowing the terminology, I'm spinning my wheels trying to find it.

(PS - I'm the only person at my work who is currently using Git. My IT department suggested using Powershell to copy my files from development to production. It'll be my fallback, but I'm hoping that Git can do it, so I can simplify my workflow)

Comment: I think you need a ci pipeline, or some sort of automated deployment/synchronisation process.

Comment: @evolutionxbox and your IT department are correct - you will probably want to use a script written in some programming language (git is a VCS framework, not a programming language) to move files around.  You could possibly shoehorn all of this into git natively using hooks - but this will likely complicate your workflow (my two cents) and git would have to call some external script anyway.